# Quickly Opening / Downloading A Bunch Of URLs

Tags: internet, download

I got a bunch of urls, that are downloadable content, in my notepad (one link at a line). Is there anyway of quickly opening / downloading all the urls? Any piece of software or browser extension.

OS: Windows

Must be free!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/)

- free, cross-platform, portable
- needs [JAVA](http://java.com)!
- you can paste a list of URLs (**Links** - **Add Links** - **Add URLs**) - but you won't even get there because right after you have copied all links it will automatically add them.

[image]

Comment: +1 JDownloader works right from the copy/paste buffer, including multiple URLs - no paste required.

Answer (score 0):

This website:

http://www.openallurls.com/

will allow you to open up to 250 URIs in your browser.

It works in Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome and Opera.